# Why does my File.HasFile always return false

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

The user will enter a customer number, then select a file to upload, then enter a description and press the save button. However, when I check to see if they've selected a file, it always returns false! I'd like to know why.

Edit: I am now using form with parameter enctype="multipart/form-data" and this is wrapped in an update panel. Both the form and update panel are in a master page

Here's the snippet of code that error handles and is getting the HasFile() value:

```
else if ( ( images.Selected == true || docs.Selected == true ) && 
                  ( Upload.HasFile == false || txtInfo.Text == string.Empty ) )
        {
            if ( Upload.HasFile == false )
                lblErrorMessage.Text = "You haven't selected a file";
            else lblErrorMessage.Text = "You must enter a description";

            validated = false;
        }
```

And here's the method that came from, the save button

```
protected void btnSaveNew_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        bool validated = true;

        lblErrorMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

        if ( txtCustomerNumber.Text.Length != 8 )
        {
            if ( txtCustomerNumber.Text.Length == 0 )
                lblErrorMessage.Text = "Hey! What about the customer number?";
            else if ( txtCustomerNumber.Text.Length > 8 )
                lblErrorMessage.Text = "Invalid Customer Number length (" + ( txtCustomerNumber.Text.Length - 8 ) + " char(s) too long)";
            else lblErrorMessage.Text = "Invalid Customer Number length (" + ( 8 - txtCustomerNumber.Text.Length ) + " char(s) short)";

            validated = false;
        }

        else if ( links.Selected == true && ( txtLink.Text == string.Empty || txtInfo.Text == string.Empty ) )
        {
            if ( txtLink.Text == string.Empty )
                lblErrorMessage.Text = "Hey! You forgot to enter a link!";
            else lblErrorMessage.Text = "You must enter a description";

            validated = false;
        }

        else if ( ( images.Selected == true || docs.Selected == true ) && 
                  ( Upload.HasFile == false || txtInfo.Text == string.Empty ) )
        {
            if ( Upload.HasFile == false )
                lblErrorMessage.Text = "You haven't selected a file";
            else lblErrorMessage.Text = "You must enter a description";

            validated = false;
        }

        else if ( txtInfoDesc.Text == string.Empty || txtInfo.Text == string.Empty )
        {
            if ( txtInfoDesc.Text == string.Empty )
                lblErrorMessage.Text = "You must enter an info description";
            else lblErrorMessage.Text = "You must enter info Data";

            validated = false;
        }

        if ( validated == false )
        {
            btnModify.Visible           = false;
            btnCreateNew.Visible        = false;
            ddlCustomerNumber.Visible   = false;
            btnSaveNew.Visible          = true;
            btnCancel.Visible           = true;
            txtCustomerNumber.Visible   = true;

            switch ( rblSection.SelectedIndex )
            {
                case 0: txtInfo.Visible = true;
                        txtLink.Visible = true;
                        break;
                case 1: 
                case 2: txtInfo.Visible = true;
                        Upload.Visible  = true;
                        break;
                case 3: txtInfo.Visible     = true;
                        txtInfoDesc.Visible = true;
                        break;
            }

            if ( GetCategoryIDCookie() != 0 )
                divData.Attributes.Add( "Style", "overflow:auto" );
        }
        else
        {
            addNewCustomerNumber( txtCustomerNumber.Text, txtInfoDesc.Text, txtInfo.Text );
            ddlCustomerNumber.Visible = true;
            divData.Attributes.Remove( "Style" );
            Response.Redirect( Request.RawUrl );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you by chance inside of an Update Panel

Comment: Do you have enctype="multipart/form-data" on your form tag?

Comment: @Jeffrey - I didn't but adding it to my form parameters hasn't changed my return value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there an update panel wrapped around the File Upload?

Comment: Yes there is. Also, this updatePanel is in the masterfile, and I've since learned I need to do PostBackTriggers but I can't find an article to explain how to do it in a masterfile since I keep getting an error that it can't find the trigger.

Comment: I ended up just deleting the update panel and that solved my problem. This bit of code was done by someone previous, and the functionality seems to be the exact same.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have enctype="multipart/form-data" on your form tag?

Comment: I didn't, but adding this didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

can you post the code for the Upload class? perhaps you erroneously initialized that variable as false and somehow forgot to set it to true during some event.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I'm trying to check if there is a file before I upload to the DB. The Upload name in my code (such as Upload.HasFile) is referring to the ID of my asp:FileUpload object