# FileUpload.HasFile give always false

Tags: c#, asp.net

this is my code where my FileUpload control is outside of update panel but when I click on save button which is under update panel give fileUploadAttachment.HasFile = false

ASPX

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="lblAttachment" Text="Attachment:" /><asp:FileUpload
            ID="fileUploadAttachment" runat="server" Width="488px" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelAction" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" ValidationGroup="Save" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" Text="Test" Enabled="false" OnClick="btnTest_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnConfirmTest" runat="server" Text="Confirm Test" Enabled="false"
                    OnClick="btnConfirmTest_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnSend" runat="server" Text="Send" Enabled="false" OnClick="btnSend_Click" />
            </ContentTemplate>

        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

CS

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CampaignBAL campaignBAL;
    string tmpFileName = "";
    User user;
    Campaign campaignDetail = new Campaign();
    int? campaignID;

    if (fileUploadAttachment.HasFile) // return always false
    {
        tmpFileName = string.Format("{0}\\{1}{2}", Server.MapPath("TempUpload"), Guid.NewGuid(), Path.GetExtension(fileUploadAttachment.PostedFile.FileName));
        fileUploadAttachment.PostedFile.SaveAs(tmpFileName);
    }
}
```

please help me how can I fix it

Comment: What type is `fileUploadAttachment` you have not provided us enough source code to help you. Furthermore there isn't a single line that actually uploads the file to the control. `The FileUpload control does not automatically save a file to the server after the user selects the file to upload. You must explicitly provide a control or mechanism to allow the user to submit the specified file. For example, you can provide a button that the user clicks to upload the file.` - Seems you have left out some of your code or simply have not written it yet.

Comment: Looking at the code again, it seems you attempt to upload/save the file, but never add the file to the control itself.  You might want to read this simple example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.fileupload.aspx

Comment: I am attaching a normal text file and doing upload using Save button click (btnSave_Click)

Comment: This is also a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941099/why-does-my-file-hasfile-always-return-false?rq=1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll need to add postback triggers for controls that post within the `UpdatePanel`:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ...>
  <Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSend" />
  </Triggers>
  ...
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Aye, thank you. Just an FYI, don't be a doofus like me and add the control of the `FileUpload` to the `<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID` -- you want the other controls which cause postbacks.

Comment: Additionally, if you have the UpdatePanel in the Master Page, then you can't add the PostBackTrigger there. So in that situation, you need to do this via code

`ScriptManager sm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
scriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(this.btnUpload); //change btnUpload to the right Button's ID`

Answer (score 1):

You Can Change Your Code in the ASP Page Like This

```
<asp:updatePanel>
<trigger>
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSend">
</trigger>
<\asp:updatePanel>
```

Comment: The PostBackTrigger control doesn't have an ID attribute